# Supressing backup files in a ls command not working

Tags: shell, ls

How do I suppress backup files displayed in ls?

I've already tried - `ls --ignore-backup` and `ls -B`

Neither suppress the back-up files created by the editors. Am I doing something wrong? or Is there another way I can get the command to display only the non-backup files? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Note that the man page says those options "do not list **implied** entries ending with ~". (Emphasis mine.) So those options will work if you list with `ls -B` but not if you use `ls -B *`.

Comment: Use the `set backup` directive in your `~/.vimrc` file to have `vim` create those `filename~` files you want `ls -B` et. al. to ignore.

Comment: What about files already existing? Am I to contend with a rm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work like that?

Try this sample here and fix it for your needs

```
$ ls --ignore='.??*' --ignore='.[^.]' --ignore='#*'
```

Comment: ^^ Please explain the command. I want it to delete only the files ending in '~'. Won't it be better to use ls --ignore='*~' ??

Comment: this is to ignore multiple files to ignore just ~ use `ls --ignore='*[~]'` another format could be `ls -d *[^~]`